# How to say Power above the Sovereign…?

Tags: classical-latin, academic-latin

I’d like to know how to say a couple of expressions in Latin.

1- “Power above the Sovereign”
2- “The Sovereigns power above the Sovereign power”.

About the first one, I don’t know if “above” should be “supra” or “ultra”, and I don’t know the best word for “power” in this case.
Regarding the second expression,… I have no idea.

Comment: But “sovereign” isn't giving you any trouble…?

Comment: “Soberanus”, isn’t it? Being a native speaker of Portuguese helps a little… In Portuguese, it’s “Soberano”. I think that’s it.

Comment: @DanielSister *Soberano* comes from the vulgar Latin *superanus*. All the Romance languages, Portuguese included, changed quite a bit from Latin. Moreover, since you marked it `classical-latin`, *superanus* wouldn't be the right word anyway.

Comment: Daniel, I think the verb "praesse" would sound better. You're talking about rule over someone. "Praesse princeps/dominator/dux".  "Potestas" is a good word for power. I didn't understand the 2nd phrase. I speak portuguese as well. You can tell me in portuguese what you're exactly looking for.